# Launch a program in vscode only if a certain condition is satisfied, e.g. the filename matches. (using launch.json)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write a `launch.json` config to run a python program called `myProg`. By design, `myProg` needs to be run from a folder containing a file named `myInput.py`; My workflow is that I open `myInput.py`, put some breakpoints there, and launch `myProg` through the following launch configuration:

```json
{
  "name": "my launcher",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "/home/user/.local/bin/myProg",
  "args": [
      "install",
      "--someOption=myOption",
      "--someOtherOption=myOtherOption"
  ],
  "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "justMyCode": false
}
```

This config works as long as I have `myInput.py` (or any other file from the folder containing `myInput.py`) open and in focus in the editor when I click "start debugging", because I have set `"cwd"` to be `"${fileDirname}"`, i.e. the folder containing the current file.

This is what I want to achieve: I want to get an error when any file other than `myInput.py` is in focus when I "start debugging".

These are the parts of the behavior that I want to change:

1- Currently when a file from a different folder is selected, the code runs until it reaches the part when it needs to load `myInput.py`, then it raises an exception and fails. What I want in this case is "not running at all", instead giving me an error, message or similar.

2- Currently when a file from the same folder as `myInput.py` is selected, the code runs fine. I would prefer it to "not run" and instead give me an error/message that the correct file is not selected.

Is there a way to achieve what I want (item 1 is more important)? In short, I want to have a condition based on which it is decided whether to run the program or not.

Assume that I cannot change "myProg" or how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#fileaskey) and the command `extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey`

If the current file does not contain `/myInput.py` choose a non existing command `DoNotRun`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "my launcher",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${input:chooseCmd}",
      "args": [
          "install",
          "--someOption=myOption",
          "--someOtherOption=myOtherOption"
      ],
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": false
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "chooseCmd",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "/myInput.py": "/home/user/.local/bin/myProg",
        "@default": "/home/user/.local/bin/DoNotRun"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an XY problem. Just set `cwd` in the launch config to `${workspaceFolder}/<path to directory containing myInput.py>`. Even the fact that it's "by design" that your program needs to be run from that directory might be an XY problem. But there's not enough info to tell.

Answer (score -1):

If i were you i would try to specify the cwd in launch.json differently, so it looks for `myInput.py` file from the {workspaceFolder} instead from file dirname. Then it would look for your file from the folder you have opened in vscode not from path of the file you are currently editing.

```json
{
  "name": "my launcher",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "/home/user/.local/bin/myProg",
  "args": [
      "install",
      "--someOption=myOption",
      "--someOtherOption=myOtherOption"
  ],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/path to input.py/myInput.py",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "justMyCode": false
}
```